# how to find out who joined the telegram channel using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I know that there are "channel actions" but I could not find how to access it

Answer (score 3):

You are probably thinking about the "admin log", which you can access with [`client.iter_admin_log`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_admin_log). Assuming you have a logged-in account, and said account is an administrator of `channel`:

```py
async for event in client.iter_admin_log(channel):
    if event.changed_title:
        print('The title changed from', event.old, 'to', event.new)
```

You will also want to read the documentation for the `event` type, [`AdminLogEvent`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.adminlogevent.AdminLogEvent), to learn what you can do with it.